# Point Reflection Across Line

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection

What is the result of reflecting a point across a line that the point is already on? For example, reflect the point $(-1, 0)$ across the $x$-axis.

Comment: It's not supposed to be defined, but I think the point itself is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection across a line preserves each point on the line.

Think of a mirror. Each point on the mirror is its own image under reflection.